# Pyflux Prediction Function

Tags: python

If anyone has some experience with Pyflux in Python I am looking for some clarification on how the Predict function works. With the following code am I correct in assuming that I am getting the prediction for the next period from the previous data? So, if `i = 30` is `df_pred.loc[i,'UD']` returning the prediction for `dfg.loc[i+1,'UD']` or the prediction for `dfg.loc[i,'UD']`? The reason I am asking is that from what the documentation says I would expect to have to call the prediction for the next period with `i+1` but that doesn't work.  Any help or advice is appreciated.

```
for i in dfg.index:
if i >= 30:
data = dfg[i-30:i]
model = pf.GARCH(data,p=3,q=3)
x = model.fit(method='MLE')
df_pred = model.predict(h=1)
dfg.loc[i,'G_Pred_UD']= df_pred.loc[i,'UD']
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes that a bug, currently `predict(x)` gives last `x` in-sample prediction.Ideally it should give `x` out-sample prediction.

https://github.com/RJT1990/pyflux/issues/95